# how to make emacs prompt me before closing the last emacs gui frame when running emacs as a daemon?

Tags: frames, emacs-daemon

I know that if I set:

```
(setq confirm-kill-emacs 'y-or-n-p)
```

Emacs prompts me before I *kill* it.

But I want emacs to prompt me before I close my last gui frame (prompting me before killing *any* frame would be very helpful already). When you run 
emacs in daemon-mode, closing the last gui frame does not kill emacs and thus the aforementioned setting does not work.

The problem is that sometimes I overpress my keybind to quit emacs windows (`evil-quit`) and I endup quiting also my current gui frame, which is annoying.

I know that before deleting the frame, emacs runs the functions that are listed in the variable `delete-frame-functions`, so I thought I could include a function there that would prompt me to query if I really wanted to kill the frame. But it is not clear from the documentation what I would have to do inside that function to stop the process of killing the frame.

Another idea would be to add an advice to evil-quit, like: if daemon-p is `t` then evil-quit have to prompt me to quit my current frame. Something like that?

I run GUI emacs from both OSx and GNU/Linux.

Comment: What OS are you running?  (OSX, for example, has a different way of handling things -- e.g., https://gist.github.com/DarwinAwardWinner/5882719 )

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may want to define a function that will ask you to confirm before closing a frame. Then you'll check if Emacs was started as a daemon, if it is the case, update the `C-x C-c` shortcut. Something in that spirit:

```
(defun ask-before-closing ()
  "Close only if y was pressed."
  (interactive)
  (if (y-or-n-p (format "Are you sure you want to close this frame? "))
      (save-buffers-kill-emacs)                                                                                            
    (message "Canceled frame close")))

(when (daemonp)
  (global-set-key (kbd "C-x C-c") 'ask-before-closing))
```

**UPDATE**: *As the OP is not near to know how to do that*

Just copy the snippet above and paste it inside your Emacs init file. It may be  `~/.emacs`, `~/.emacs.el`, or `~/.emacs.d/init.el`. Then, relaunch Emacs.

Comment: that 's a nice idea, but I really use just `evil-quit` to close emacs, frames and windows. I never use `C-x C-c`. The trick here would be to query if there is only one window active at the moment, and if that is indeed the case, evil-quit would close the current frame without asking me, which is annoying. So instead we would `y-or-n-p` the user. I think that could be the way to go.

Comment: Except I am not near to know how to do that.

Comment: @ninrod Answer updated.

Comment: thanks but I meant I did not know how to advice a function.

Comment: @ninrod My answer is not about function advice. And I do not use `evil`, so I cannot help you for that point, sorry.

Comment: Note that if you use Emacs in terminal, the `(save-buffers-kill-emacs)` should be `(save-buffers-kill-terminal)`