# How to prompt to ask for confirmation when C-x C-c in emacsclient?

Tags: emacsclient, desktop, exit, prompt

I use

```
(setq desktop-save 'ask)
```

in my init.el, so every time I `C-x C-c` to exit Emacs, it will prompt to ask if saving desktop or not; I use this trick to avoid accidentally exiting Emacs.

But after using `emacsclient` to speed up Emacs's startup time,

```
emacsclient -a "" -t
```

`C-x C-c` will not prompt to ask for saving desktop, it will exit Emacs immediately.

Is there anything I can do to prompt for confirmation when `C-x C-c` in `emacsclient?` I doesn't have to be prompting for saving desktop, any confirmation will be OK to me.

**BTW:** I use Emacs in terminal, inside a server without GUI.

Comment: `C-x C-c` doesn't exit Emacs when in daemon mode, it only closes the current frame, while the editing server is still hanging around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer from https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/30475/794

The version is tweaked version from the answer in the link

```
(defun ask-before-closing ()
  "Prompt for confirmation for emacsclient(not daemon) like confirm-kill-emacs for running Emacs without daemon."
  (interactive)
  (if (y-or-n-p (format "Really exit Emacs? "))
          (save-buffers-kill-terminal)
        (message "Canceled frame close!")))
(when (daemonp)
  (global-set-key (kbd "C-x C-c") 'ask-before-closing))
```

Use it to avoid accidentally exiting emacsclient (not exit emacs daemon) running with daemon.

And use

```
(setq confirm-kill-emacs #'y-or-n-p)
```

to avoid accidentally exiting Emacs if running without daemon.

Comment: This is exactly the idea I had and was going to answer with. However, I found an alternative you might want to consider.

Answer (score 2):

> `C-x C-c` will not prompt to ask for saving desktop, it will exit Emacs immediately.

<kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>C-c</kbd> (`save-buffers-kill-terminal`) does not actually kill the server by default, unless the client invoking it was started with the `--no-wait` switch and there are no other remaining Emacs frames[1][2].

> Is there anything I can do to prompt for confirmation when `C-x C-c` in `emacsclient`? I doesn't have to be prompting for saving desktop, any confirmation will be OK to me.

As [Sam mentions](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/48620/15748), there is the user option `confirm-kill-emacs` you can configure[1]. This is the best place to hook into, as it is the final thing done before calling `kill-emacs`. This means the standard checks for modified buffers, active processes, and the hook `kill-emacs-query-functions` all get a chance to run first. Alternatively, you could add a function to `kill-emacs-query-functions`, but note that its ordering can be important[3].

Since `save-buffers-kill-terminal` does not usually kill a daemon Emacs, though, you must somehow ensure `save-buffers-kill-emacs` gets called instead, if you truly want to kill the server. FWIW, I achieve this in my own configuration by globally remapping[4] `save-buffers-kill-terminal` to `save-buffers-kill-emacs`. YMMV. Here are the relevant incantations:

```el
(global-set-key [remap save-buffers-kill-terminal] #'save-buffers-kill-emacs)

(setq confirm-kill-emacs #'yes-or-no-p)
```

If you want to get prompted only when you're running `emacsclient`, however, just modify the `confirm-kill-emacs` predicate:

```el
(defun my-confirm-kill-daemon (prompt)
  "Ask whether to kill daemon Emacs with PROMPT.
Intended as a predicate for `confirm-kill-emacs'."
  (or (not (daemonp))
      (yes-or-no-p prompt)))

(setq confirm-kill-emacs #'my-confirm-kill-daemon)
```

---

- [1]: [`(emacs) Exiting`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Exiting.html)
- [2]: [`(emacs) emacsclient Options`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/emacsclient-Options.html)
- [3]: [`(elisp) Killing Emacs`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Killing-Emacs.html)
- [4]: [`(elisp) Remapping Commands`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Remapping-Commands.html)

Comment: Thanks, but your first solution is not working, it kills Emacs daemon too, and the second solution doesn't work either, it exits emacsclient(not daemon) without prompt. I just want to kill the emacsclient with confirmation instead of the daemon if there is daemon. and `(setq confirm-kill-emacs #'y-or-n-p)` is for Emacs running without daemon

Answer (score 1):

You could try setting `confirm-kill-emacs` to `y-or-n-p` in your config:

```el
(setq confirm-kill-emacs #'y-or-n-p)
```

Works for me.

Comment: This is just a replacement for `desktop-save` to avoid accidentally exiting Emacs, putting this line in init.el doesn't prevent exiting emacsclient, did't you tried it?

Comment: Yes, I did try it and it worked for me. I didn't test extensively, though, so I might not have tested under the same conditions that you were operating under when you saw the problem.

Comment: Adding onto my previous comment. What I actually did was start Emacs normally and then enable server mode using `server-start`. Then my solution Works On My Machine™